# Order two @variables together by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a messaging system with two tables: Message and MessageCopy, where each time a message is sent it generates a message_copy for each recipient (with info like read, saved, deleted, etc.).

I would like to show a 'conversation' with sent and received messages for my user, and I would like to splice together sent and received messages, ordered by `created_at`.

Here are my two currently separated relations.

```
@sentmessages = Message.where("author_id = ? AND project_id = ?", current_user.id, @project.id).order("created_at DESC")
@receivedmessages = MessageCopy.where("recipient_id = ? AND project_id = ?", current_user.id, @project.id).order("created_at DESC")
```

I'd like to put these together into one relation using Rails if possible rather than MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand correctly - you want a single variable that stores these objects ordered by date.

`(@sentmessages + @receivedmessages).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse`

Comment: Hi @Vise - so sorry for not being active on this. The problem I had with `(@sentmessages + @receivedmessages)` is that they are different models. One is the actual message, the other is the received copy of a message. I'm trying to put together a 'conversation' where events are organized by date.